# Comma separators in Fortran

Tags: io, fortran

I have come across the following issue with Fortran: that in reading a character array, for example, or any list in actuality, from a data file with fmt=*, both non-interquote blanks AND commas are natively considered as delimiters for the elements in the array/list. The fact that commas act as delimiters is a big problem for me.

So the question is: do you know of any semantic option or compilation directive in Fortran that permits to consider the commas in input files as characters and not as delimiters,
with the only delimiters being blanks? As an specific example, I would like that when reading a record like:

```
x,y,z
```

with:

```
read (7,*) adummy
```

would result in `adummy` (a scalar character variable) getting the value `x,y,z` not `x`.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to specify formatting to match your data record, i.e. use character data descriptor when specifying the format:

```
read(7,fmt='(A)')adummy
```

will result in `adummy` having value `x,y,z`, assuming it is a variable of sufficient length.

However this method will not treat blanks as delimiters either, so if you want to read commas as character strings but have blanks as delimiter, the common way to achieve this is to read the whole record into the character variable and do the splitting into separate variables afterwards.

Comment: Thank you IRO-bot. The formatted read does indeed work for the simple case that I gave as an example but as you have pointed it does not work, for example, for reading a record: x,y,z

Comment: @user1499420 I am not sure what you mean - can you please clarify in your question? What exactly does not work?

Comment: (Complete comment)Thank you IRO-bot. The formatted read does indeed work for the simple case that I gave as an example but as you have pointed it does not work, for example, for reading a record: x,y,z u,v,w into adummy if this is a character aray of shape (/2/), which is more like my real-life problem. Also, the fmt=* functionality of reading an array through different records in the input files would be lost. In my problem data can sometimes be all in the same record/row or in consecutive ones. I am trying to avoid writing a proper parsing routine but using instead the funtionality of fmt=*

Comment: @user1499420 My opinion is that writing a parser for your data would be your best choice. If you insist on using default format input, there may be some non-standard compiler options that provide this functionality, but I am not aware of them, so you would need to look into compilers' documentation.

Comment: Thank you IRO-bot, that was sadly my understanding as well but I wanted to learn the opinion of the experts. I think that optionally allowing to restrict the separators for fmt=* to only blanks would be a very good idea for future Fortran installments. It may help a lot in cases like this, which I guess are not unusual.